# why won't my if elif statement work for my django production environment?

Tags: python, django, development-environment

I'm trying to set up a local and a production settings for my django project I've tried this

```
from .my_pass import LOCAL

from .base import *


if LOCAL == 'local':
    from .local import *

elif not LOCAL == 'production':
    from .production import *
```

and it wont work. If I do this

```
example.com/.,mnwnci
```

it shows all my debug information. How can I fix that? so that in development I see the debug info and in production I don't

Comment: why elif not ?  if LOCAL is production then that is production environment right ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `elif not LOCAL == 'production'` there, which i guess is wrong, because you have to import from production if `LOCAL == 'production'`, right? Then change the `elif not LOCAL == 'production'` to `elif LOCAL == 'production'`

Comment: or just use ```else```

Comment: @JOSEFtw haha, true

Comment: @nothingness Look at my answer, replace `elif not LOCAL == 'production` to `elif LOCAL == 'production'`

Comment: I did it's not working. Really sucks not having a mentor right next to you so you can see. trying this multiple settings for different environments has become more trouble than it's worth

Comment: @nothingness So, in your `mypass.py`, there is a `LOCAL` variable set to `production` and in `production.py`, there is a `DEbUG = False` statement?

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed no the LOCAL is set to 'local' but production.py is set to DEbUG = False

Comment: @nothingness then set LOCAL to `production` and see if it is showing DEBUG info, because if in `local.py`, DEBUG is set to `True` then of course it will show all the debug info. so change LOCAL to `production`